# UITableView paging causing autoscroll jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a basic UITableView with a UI having, lets say, n number of cells.
(visualize relatively thin cells, about 4 in one iPhone5 screen)

What I am aiming to do is when the user taps on a cell it expands to the height of the whole screen and the tableview becomes paginated.

Here is where I am doing this through code:
**NOTE:** The whole thing is animated.

```
void (^tableBlock)(void) = ^{
        int bonus = 10;
        int diff = self.chooser.frame.origin.y - self.invitesTable.frame.origin.y+bonus;
        [self.invitesTable setFrame:CGRectMake(self.invitesTable.frame.origin.x, self.chooser.frame.origin.y+bonus, self.invitesTable.frame.size.width, self.invitesTable.frame.size.height-diff)];
        CGAffineTransform moveTable = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, diff);

        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    };

    void (^tableCompletionBlock)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

        BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

        NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
        [self.selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            [tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView endUpdates];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

            [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

            [tableView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        }];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:tableBlock completion:tableCompletionBlock];
```

I am facing an issue after paging has been enabled, where if I have expanded any cell other than the first cell, causes the tableview to auto scroll downwards the approximate height of 1 previous tableview cell.

How do I stop this side effect once paging has been enabled.

Upon debugging I noticed it has nothing to do with the UITableView updates as even on removing them i.e. just simply by enabling scrolling the bug persists.

Comment: Try removing all animations. Does the bug persist? Also, where exactly is the *-(void)tableBlock* working?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to take a stab at this, but can you provide more code? I need to see how the chooser fits in relation to the table.

Comment: you could take that as a static value : (say 50)
let me see if i could create a sample project and isolate the code causing the issue

Comment: you have to take offSet value and set it for atScrollPosition: Hope it will work. You set property scroll position top might be causing issue.